# React use data in table, take data from input field and send request to database using data after clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very new to react, I currently have a table shown below. I have two columns that are data pulled from my database, an input field column, and buttons to the side. Essentially it's for inventory management. You'll see the quantity you have in your database, if you want to restock or use the inventory you'll add the amount in the quantity input field then press restock or use and it'll send a request to the database to do the according action. This probably isn't the best way to make such a table since I've pulled code from several different articles and tutorials. Any advice on how to move forward and have my restock/use buttons working that'll use the input field data and quantity would be great.

[Picture of table in react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb3bV.png)

Here's currently what I have in my render function

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Restock/Use</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style={{marginTop:20}}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Current Quantity</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.inventoryList(this.state.inventory)}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

My inventory state that I have mapped is here

```
inventoryList = (inventory) =>{
        
        return inventory.map((inventory, index) => (
            <tr>
                <td>{index}</td>
                <td>{inventory.description}</td>
                <td>{inventory.quantity}</td>
                <input type='number'></input>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        <button type="button" id='btnRestock' class="btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={this.restockInventory}>Restock</button>
                        <button type="button" id='btnRestock' class="btn-danger btn-sm">Use</button>
                    </div>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
        ))
    }
```

My button function that I have is below

```
restockInventory(index){
        console.log('HELLLOO')
        console.log(this.state.inventory)
    }
```

Comment: So what's the specific problem and can you provide an error log that is produced when it doesn't work?

Comment: both buttons in the toolbar have the same id.... not the cause of your issue - but evert id needs to be unique. - also your restockInventory expects an index argument to be passed to it - but the onClick does not.

Comment: @TheGrandJ There's not an error. I'm just trying to do what I described ahead and am looking for help in doing so. I'm lost on how to proceed forward.